# Hiding search bar of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` with some customizations and I create a UISearchDisplayController like this

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
```

I want the search bar to appear on navigation bar so I also set

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true;
```

Now the search bar shows in the Navigation Bar, but I want to show the search bar of my `UISearchDisplayController` only when I tap on a Navigation Bar Button Item. I want to have a behaviour like:

1. Hide the search bar initially
2. Show search bar when a navigation bar button is clicked
3. Hide the search bar when I tap "Cancel" button of
   the search bar

I tried to hide/unhide it like:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = YES;
```

but the code doesn't seem working. I've spent a lot time searching the solution to have the behaviour I want and still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: You've got three tasks lined up to complete. Are any of these working?

Comment: None of those steps is working as I haven't found out a way to hide/undide `UISearchDisplayController`'s search bar.

Comment: Would you be content with having the search bar scrolled off screen (not animated) and beneath the top Nav bar, tapping the Nav bar retracts it to reveal search bar beneath (animated), click cancel on search bar reinstates Nav bar back over top of search bar (animated)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
CGRect searchFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
searchFrame.size.height = 0;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = searchFrame;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = YES;
```

**EDIT:** I just tried with below code and it worked. See if this helps you!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}


- (void)test {
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this code in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`. But the search bar is still showing.

Comment: I see you are passing `self.seachbar`. How about `self.searchbar.hidden = YES`?

Comment: That's not working too. Looks like hiding `UISearchDisplayController`'s `searchBar` does not work when `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true;` is set?

Comment: I need to find that out. BTW... If you are not supporting iOS < 8 then why don't you use `UISearchController` instead.

Comment: I support iOS 7. That's why.

Comment: Take a look at my updated post. I am not sure if your buttons are part of the same bar which I am hiding now. But I think this is the only option we have. If this hides your button, see if UI can be tweaked a bit to re-position the buttons. @PhyoMinThu

Comment: Just tried out your code. Thanks for your help but my buttons are on the same bar with it so they went hidden too. Still no idea and I'm now thinking to use a `UISearchBar` (which I can hide/unhide easily) and my own `UITableView` to mimic what `UISearchDisplayController` does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a suitable solution?

To complete task 1, in your TVC lifecycle method `viewDidLoad`, insert a non-animated scroll that places the search bar beneath the Nav bar...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Scroll off screen the search bar (44 points)
    [[self tableView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];

    // other code for method
}
```

To complete task 2, in your TVC create a custom action method associated with a `UIBarButtonItem`, that effectively hides the Nav bar, at the same time revealing the search bar...

```
- (IBAction)hideNavBar:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]

}
```

To complete task 3, in your TVC use the `UISearchDisplayController` Delegate method to effectively display the Nav bar and at the same time hide the search bar...

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [[self tableView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];

    // You might also like to...
    [self setSearchBarText:nil]; // if you are using a property to hold the search bar text
    [self setSearchResults:nil]; // if you are using a property to hold the search results

}
```